# How do I show the equivalence of these commands in denotational semantics

Tags: denotational-semantics

I do not even know where to start with this assignment. I need to prove the following directly, that is, without using any Theorems or Lemmas. I have the following definitions:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\eta &: & A \to A_\bot\\
\eta\ a & = & \left\lfloor a \right\rfloor\\
(\star) & : & A_\bot \times (A\to B_\bot) \to B_\bot\\
\bot \star f & = & \bot\\
\left\lfloor a \right\rfloor\star f & = & f\ a\\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{C}[\![c]\!] & : & \Sigma \to \Sigma_\bot\\
\mathcal{C}[\![\text{skip}]\!] & = & \lambda\sigma.\eta\ \sigma\\
\mathcal{C}[\![X:=a]\!] & = & \lambda\sigma.\eta\ (\sigma[X\mapsto\mathcal{A}[\![a]\!]\sigma)\\
\mathcal{C}[\![c_0;c_1]\!] & = & \lambda\sigma.(\mathcal{C}[\![c_0]\!]\sigma\star\lambda\sigma_1.\mathcal{C}[\![c_1]\!]\sigma_1)\\
\mathcal{C}[\![\text{if }b\text{ then }c_0\text{ else }c_1]\!] & = &\lambda\sigma.cond\ (\mathcal{B}[\![b]\!]\sigma, \mathcal{C}[\![c_0]\!]\sigma, \mathcal{C}[\![c_1]\!]\sigma) \\
\mathcal{C}[\![\text{while }b\text{ do }c_0]\!] & = & \varphi, \text{where }\varphi = \lambda\sigma.cond\ (\mathcal{B}[\![b]\!]\sigma, \mathcal{C}[\![c_0]\!]\sigma\star \varphi, \eta\ \sigma)\\
\end{array}$$

And i need to show:
$$\mathcal{C}[\![c_0;(c_1;c_2)]\!] = \mathcal{C}[\![(c_0;c_1);c_2]\!]$$

My problem is that I do not know how to manipulate these expressions. Can anyone guide me? This is a homework assignment. I wrote out the expressions like this, but don't know where to go from here:

$$\mathcal{C}[\![c_0;(c_1;c_2)]\!]\sigma = \mathcal{C}[\![c_0]\!]\sigma\star\lambda\sigma_1.\mathcal{C}[\![c_1;c_2]\!]\sigma_1$$
$$\mathcal{C}[\![(c_0;c_1);c_2]\!]\sigma = \mathcal{C}[\![c_0;c_1]\!]\sigma\star \lambda\sigma_1.\mathcal{C}[\![c_2]\!]\sigma_1 = \mathcal{C}[\![c_0]\!]\sigma\star\lambda c_2.\mathcal{C}[\![c_1]\!]\sigma_2\star\lambda\sigma_1.\mathcal{C}[\![c_2]\!]\sigma_1$$

Comment: I edited the formulas, please verify that I did not make any mistake.

Comment: Looks good, thanks